# Weather app: J2me constructor

Tags: java, java-me, midp, lcdui

I have a problem with a weather app am working on. The constructor is supposed to create a list but when the app runs, it just shows a blank screen.

```
ERROR:
';' expected

no suitable constructor found for List(javax.microedition.lcdui.List)
    constructor javax.microedition.lcdui.List.List(java.lang.String,int,java.lang.String[],javax.microedition.lcdui.Image[]) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
    constructor javax.microedition.lcdui.List.List(java.lang.String,int) is not applicable
      (actual and formal argument lists differ in length)
```

---

//class with constructor

```
public class WeatherMIDlet extends BaseMIDlet implements CommandListener {

private List list3;

private List getWeatherLocationView(List list3) {

        if (weatherConditionSearch == null) {
            weatherConditionSearch = new WeatherConditionSearch(this, list3);
        }
        return weatherConditionSearch; //list should dislay here!
    }
```

//class where I want to create a list of my local cites

```
public class WeatherConditionSearch extends List implements CommandListener {

    private Command okCmd, backCmd;
    private TextField locationTfld;
    private BaseMIDlet midlet;
        private List list;

    public WeatherConditionSearch(BaseMIDlet midlet, List list3) //super class is List
{
        super(list3);//error is at this line
        this.midlet = midlet;
        lists();
        addCommand(okCmd);
        addCommand(backCmd);
        setCommandListener(this);
    }

    private void lists() {
            okCmd = new Command("Get", Command.OK, 0);
            backCmd = new Command("Back", Command.BACK, 1);
                if (list == null) {                                 
            list = new List("Cities", Choice.IMPLICIT);                                    
            list.append("Kampala", null);
            list.append("Entebbe", null);
            list.append("Mubende", null);
            list.setCommandListener(this);
            list.setSelectedFlags(new boolean[]{false, false, false});                                  
        }
```

Comment: *What* error is at that line? How does that impact the creation of the city list? Where is this list displayed?

Comment: Ok, your edit helps a little. Maybe this makes more sense to a JME developer, but: what is the superclass for `WeatherConditionSearch`, and why are you passing a `List` instance to its constructor?

Comment: (I wish you'd comment here - it'd be easier to track)

Comment: You're trying to invoke the `List` constructor when you call `super(list3)`, but `javax.microedition.lcdui.List.List` doesn't have a constructor that accepts a `List` (presumably another `javax.microedition.lcdui.List.List`, in this case). See http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/List.html. Do you know why you're calling `super` in your code?

Comment: Why do you think that's the right thing to do? Where does `list3` come from? Maybe you should call the `List(String title, int listType, String[] stringElements, Image[] imageElements)` constructor, passing it a list of city names.

Comment: thanks for the link.
i've figured out what to do now!

Comment: Oh, ignatius. The [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html) should be your first, nay, your *zeroth* stop when developing Java apps. Always start there.

Answer (score 1):

Superclass for WeatherConditionSearch is List.

You're trying to invoke the List constructor when you call `super(list3)`, but `javax.microedition.lcdui.List.List` doesn't have a constructor that accepts a List, see [API documentation](http://java.sun.com/javame/reference/apis/jsr118/javax/microedition/lcdui/List.html).

From what you describe, you rather should call the `List(String title, int listType, String[] stringElements, Image[] imageElements)` constructor, passing it a list of city names.

<sub>The [JavaDocs](http://docs.oracle.com/javame/config/cldc/ref-impl/midp2.0/jsr118/index.html) should be your first, nay, your *zeroth* stop when developing Java apps. Always start there.</sub>